# Folium map in iPython not displaying map. Throws error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined'

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ipython, leaflet, folium

Attempting to display a basic map in iPython using folium leaflet library. 
Recent install of iPython through Anaconda with Folium installed with Pip. Confirmed everything is up to date

ran this code in iPython

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)
map.create_map('map.html')
map
```

I receive a blank frame. I checked the console on the html. I receive a number of Failed to load resource: `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` tracing back to an `Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined`. I checked the html document and found the leaflet reference looks like this:

```
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js">
```

I assume the issue is with the relative link but I have no found information in the folium docs to resolve this issue.

Thanks ya'll for the help. I look forward to paying it forward.

Comment: can you show us the entire rendered html document?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [tutorial on Folium in iPython Notebooks](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/05/05/folium/) quite helpful. Also, I did a detailed answer on this other [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969991/folium-map-not-displaying/) which seems related.

To display in the iPython notebook, you need to generate the html with the myMap._build_map() method, wrap it in an iframe, and return the iFrame to iPython for display.

Here's an example for your situation:

```
import folium  
from IPython.display import HTML
myMap = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)
myMap._build_map() 
mapWidth, mapHeight = (400,500) # width and height of the iFrame in pixels
srcdoc = myMap.HTML.replace('"', '&quot;')
embed = HTML('<iframe srcdoc="{}" '
             'style="width: {}px; height: {}px; display:block; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; '
             'border: none"></iframe>'.format(srcdoc, width, height))
embed
```

Note that the `.create_map()` method will save the full map HTML to a file, while you want to keep the HTML code handy for presentation in iPython- this is why we use ._build_map() instead. The line beginning with `embed` is where the magic happens- we wrap the HTML content generated by folium in an iframe which can be styled as desired, and then is returned as the cell's output. IPython internally calls `.display()` on the results returned to the cell, so you should have a nice, centered map.