# Folium map not displaying

Tags: python, canopy, folium

Running on canopy version 1.5.5.3123
With;

Folium Version: 0.1.2, Build: 1

The following code;

```
import folium  
import pandas as pd
LDN_COORDINATES = (51.5074, 0.1278)  
from IPython.display import HTML
import shapefile
#create empty map zoomed in on London
LDN_COORDINATES = (51.5074, 0.1278) 
map = folium.Map(location=LDN_COORDINATES, zoom_start=12)
display(map)
```

Returns

```
<folium.folium.Map at 0x10c01ae10>
```

But nothing else.

How do i get to display a map within an ipython notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this tutorial on Folium in iPython Notebooks](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/05/05/folium/) quite helpful. The raw Folium instance that you've created isn't enough to get iPython to display the map- you need to do a bit more work to get some HTML that iPython can render.

To display in the iPython notebook, you need to generate the html with the myMap._build_map() method, and then wrap it in an iFrame with styling for iPython.

```
import folium  
from IPython.display import HTML, display
LDN_COORDINATES = (51.5074, 0.1278) 
myMap = folium.Map(location=LDN_COORDINATES, zoom_start=12)
myMap._build_map()
mapWidth, mapHeight = (400,500) # width and height of the displayed iFrame, in pixels
srcdoc = myMap.HTML.replace('"', '&quot;')
embed = HTML('<iframe srcdoc="{}" '
             'style="width: {}px; height: {}px; display:block; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; '
             'border: none"></iframe>'.format(srcdoc, width, height))
embed
```

Where by returning `embed` as the output of the iPython cell, iPython will automatically call `display.display()` on the returned iFrame. In this context, you should only need to call `display()` if you're rendering something else afterwards or using this in a loop or a function.

Also, note that using `map` as a variable name may might be confused with the .map() method of several classes.

Comment: myMap._build_map()    _build_map() doesn't exit anymore. They took it out of the folium. How should we solve the problem if we don't have _build_map()?

Answer (score 17):

You can also save the map as html and then open it with webbrowser.

```
import folium
import webbrowser


class Map:
    def __init__(self, center, zoom_start):
        self.center = center
        self.zoom_start = zoom_start
    
    def showMap(self):
        #Create the map
        my_map = folium.Map(location = self.center, zoom_start = self.zoom_start)

        #Display the map
        my_map.save("map.html")
        webbrowser.open("map.html")


#Define coordinates of where we want to center our map
coords = [51.5074, 0.1278]
map = Map(center = coords, zoom_start = 13)
map.showMap()
```

Answer (score 8):

_build_map() doesn't exist anymore. The following code worked for me

```
import folium
from IPython.display import display
LDN_COORDINATES = (51.5074, 0.1278)
myMap = folium.Map(location=LDN_COORDINATES, zoom_start=12)
display(myMap)
```

Comment: Running this in IPython on MacOS I get `<folium.folium.Map at 0x10391f850>`

Answer (score 6):

Considering the above answers, another simple way is to use it with **Jupiter Notebook**.

for example (on the Jupiter notebook):

```
import folium

london_location = [51.507351, -0.127758]

m = folium.Map(location=london_location, zoom_start=15)
m
```

and see the result when calling the 'm'.

Comment: The question is precisely not in Jupiter Notebook

Comment: @Joachim yes, I mentioned: With considering the above answers, another simple way is to use Jupiter notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are using an outdated version of Folium?

This ipython notebook clarifies some of the differences between 1.2 and 2, and it explains how to put folium maps in iframes.
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bibmartin/folium/blob/issue288/examples/Popups.ipynb

And the code would look something like this (found in the notebook above, it adds a marker, but one could just take it out):

```
m = folium.Map([43,-100], zoom_start=4)

html="""
    <h1> This is a big popup</h1><br>
    With a few lines of code...
    <p>
    <code>
        from numpy import *<br>
        exp(-2*pi)
    </code>
    </p>
    """
iframe = folium.element.IFrame(html=html, width=500, height=300)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)

folium.Marker([30,-100], popup=popup).add_to(m)

m
```

The docs are up and running, too, http://folium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use iframes in 2022. To display the map, simply use the

`{{ map | safe }}` tag in html and `_repr_html_()` method in you view. It is also not necessary to save the map to the template

**sample.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    start_coords = (46.9540700, 142.7360300)
    folium_map = folium.Map(location=start_coords, zoom_start=14)
    return folium_map._repr_html_()
```

**template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ folium_map | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is that `@app.route('/')`. It gives `NameError: name 'app' is not defined`. Please provide complete code and explanation

Comment: @not2qubit  Read this https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/

Answer (score -2):

i have same error and nothing work for me
finally i found it
print(dir(folium.Map))
see method save dose not exist instead use