# Folium heatmap not displaying in Jupiter notebook in Internet Explorer

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium

I am trying to plot a heatmap similar to the one from https://alysivji.github.io/getting-started-with-folium.html. The output should look something like this picture but for the area of the North Sea.

[image]

However when I try to plot the colorfull dots over the map, Jupyter notebooks output is blank.
This my code:

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

m = folium.Map([52.5, 2], zoom_start=5.5)
m
```

Gives me this, which is what I want:

[image]

Now I want to add 10 dots to the map, my data and code is the following:

```
divvyStations =df = pd.DataFrame({'Xpos': Xpos1[0], 'Ypos': Ypos1[0],'Density': Density})
print(divvyStations)
```

OUT:

```
   Density      Xpos       Ypos
0        1 -3.758242  50.099575
1        1 -3.780331  50.110645
2        1 -3.740984  50.113747
3        1 -3.802421  50.121719
4        1 -3.763073  50.124821
5        1 -3.723726  50.127922
6        1 -3.824510  50.132793
7        1 -3.785162  50.135895
8        1 -3.745815  50.138992
9        1 -3.706468  50.142094
```

And then I try to plot the points:

```
for index, row in divvyStations.iterrows():
   folium.CircleMarker([row['Ypos'],row['Xpos']],
                    radius=15,
                    #popup=row['Density'],
                    fill_color="#3db7e4", # divvy color
                   ).add_to(m)
m
```

Which gives me this nice screen:
[image]

**Why is there no map?**

I already checked questions: [Folium map not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969991/folium-map-not-displaying), [Python Folium Map Not Displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047826/python-folium-map-not-displaying)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The screenshot of your notebook contains incorrect code as you are including `Density` in your location parameter

Comment: @BobHaffner I already tried deleting row['Density'], it gives me the same blank output.

Comment: Ok, i was able to get the 10 plotted using your code.  Not sure why you're getting a blank map.   Out of curiosity, does saving your map and opening it in the browser work?  And what browser are you using?

Comment: @BobHaffner I did it in Chrome and now it works, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ok, good deal. Happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Anaconda opened Jupyter Notebook in **internet explorer** and it **didn't work**. When running it in **Chrome it worked** just fine. To change the browser Anaconda opens it in check question [how to open Jupyter notebook in chrome on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829761/how-to-open-jupyter-notebook-in-chrome-on-windows?rq=1) . Credits to @BobHaffner for the tip!