# Folium: not displaying map in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, folium

I am running simple code from documentation:

```
import folium

london_location = [51.507351, -0.127758]

m = folium.Map(location=london_location, zoom_start=15)
m
```

but the result is:
[image]

as far as I know it should work with jupyter without any problems.
Before it need a method on map as in this [so questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969991/folium-map-not-displaying):

My set up:

- python 3.6
- conda 4.6.8
- folium 0.8.3
- jupyter 1.0.0

Comment: Have you tried to restart kernel? Sometimes it helps with display problems

Comment: @maria unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried to reopen the whole environment.

Comment: Can you use your browser developer tools to check the output of the console? There will probably be a Javascript error message there. It will help us debug this.