# folium map not showing datbricks python

Tags: databricks, folium, azure-databricks

I am working on Databricks and have a folium map:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib as plt
import os
import folium
from IPython.display import display

map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
map_osm
```

I get the following:

```
<folium.folium.Map at 0x7f9978eec748>
```

I tried [Folium map not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969991/folium-map-not-displaying) to no avail.

Any suggestions

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook or any other?

Comment: did it work????

Comment: Unfortunately not. my output was: Out[4]: False

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook in DataBricks

Comment: It did work on my machine. THere must be some problem with your setup.

Comment: Very odd. I tried running a matplot on the same cluster and came with a blank as well. I tried your suggestion on a new cluster, and got the same result --> False

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import folium
import webbrowser
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
map_osm.save('map.html')
webbrowser.open('map.html')
```

The output of the function is a HTML file and Python IDLE fails to render the  html document unless explicitly called. You can also try using the same code on Jupyter notebook which runs on a browser and can render html map at ease.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the map into HTML then displaying worked for me in Databricks using Python 3.5

```
world_map = folium.Map()
html_map = world_map._repr_html_()
displayHTML(html_map)
```

The original answer came from Databricks forums by ShumZZ: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/444/how-to-create-maps-in-databricks.html

Comment: simple way to show the maps, dont need install anything, very nice!